# Php : replace image src path using php script

Tags: php, mysql, magento-1.9

I want to create php script to update img src path.

**old result  :**

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank"><img src="{{media url=''}}wysiwyg/images/img_07.jpg" border="1">
```

**expected result :**

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank"><img src="{{media url='wysiwyg/images/img_07.jpg'}}" border="1">
```

I used this below code :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "testing";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_nm WHERE attribute_id = 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo htmlentities($row["value"]) . "<br>"; //old result text display from here.
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

What should i need to change to get expected result?

Comment: What exactly is in here `echo htmlentities($row["value"]) . "<br>";`? Can you show us? How do you display that in img src?

Comment: @BudimirSkrtic old result is htmlentities($row["value"]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to get the expected result

```
$patterns = ["'}}","jpg","png","jpeg","gif"];
$replacements = ["","jpg'}}","png'}}","jpeg'}}","gif'}}"];
$row["value"] = str_replace($patterns, $replacements, $row["value"]);
```

Comment: Your code remove img extensions. I mean it remove jpg also.

Comment: Can you please also add like jpg,png,gif,jpeg this also working ?